# where ask for personal opinion or recommendations?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In a community I would like to hear personal opinion or recommendation from more experienced users about instruments, keyboards, guitars or DAW softwares.

However is forbidden to "Questions asking us to recommend or ask for opinionated answers". My question is, where can I ask these questions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask these questions in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Reddit's [/r/musicians](https://www.reddit.com/r/musicians) is another possible place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

For guitar:

http://www.thegearpage.net/

http://www.thefretboard.co.uk/

For Bass:

https://www.talkbass.com/

http://basschat.co.uk/

All very active.

For keyboards, you could try https://www.gearslutz.com/, though its broad focus is production in general. I'm sure there are other sites I'm not aware of.